# why we are using `<div></div>` tag so many times compare to other elements?

Tags: html

For Example:

```
<div style="color:#0000FF">
  <h3>This is a heading</h3>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

why like this? and i need to know proper reason.

Answer (score 1):

The `<div>` has various uses in a HTML document. It helps in dividing a document into different parts and sections.

CSS:
You could add different CSS style to different divisions in a html document. This means that you can have a variety of effects and styles in a single document. If there was no division, it would mean that your web page would have a single background color throughout. But divisions help you in giving different background colors and effects to different portions.

Segregating Code:
You could also divide html documents into divisions to segregate different parts of code so that it becomes easier to manage.

These are some very basic uses. There could be more. You will find it's importance as you start writing HTML documents.

Answer (score 1):

In HTML there are number of tags such as `div`, `ul-li`, `<a`, `span` `<p>` `<h1>` etc. each tag has got its own function. Like `<a` is used to give links, `<p>` tag is used to place body text, `h1` and `h2`.. are used as heading etc. `div` is a block element and it acts as container. So we use `div` to place all other elements inside `<div>`s. It is a strong foundation of HTML and used to properly structure the HTML pages. All other tags mentioned above are usually placed inside `<div>`. With CSS you can make any layout design to HTML exactly the same in pixel perfection.